# Android Telephony System using Wireless Network

Tags: android, sip, sip-server, android-wireless

Error here is unreachable statement, but I have imported Sipmanager.  Still I'm getting error.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public  SipManager mSipManager = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
        if(mSipManager == null){
            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm Sorry , That I put an off topic question. I hope I will do good next time. @Bob Malooga

Comment: Appreciated @demongolem